# subscript is set too low in math-mode with xits-math

Tags: math-mode, luatex, subscripts, unicode-math

I use `unicode-math` with `xits-math` as math font and `asana-math` for math double-struck symbols. I compile with `lualatex`, and my packages are from TeXlive 2011.

Now, when use `asana-math` mixed with `xits`, I have the following problem:

In math mode, if I type `$\deg_s ϕ$` my output is

> [image: subscript too low]

What I want is:

> [image: subscript okay]

Here is a minimal working example

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

    \setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
    \setmathfont[range={\mathbb}]{Asana-Math.otf}

\begin{document}
    $\deg_s \phi$
\end{document}
```

This problem also occurs when I use only `asana-math` as math font, so that's probably from where it comes.
I need asana-math for its double-struck math characters which I prefer over xits-math's.

Is this a bug or is it supposed to be set so low? Can I fix this somehow? Is it unclean to mix fonts?

Edit: I now updated the question according to what I found out. Sorry for being so uninformative before, I underestimated the problem. : - ) (Thanks, Caramdir)

Comment: @Caramdir Me neither, at least not as simply as I thought. (This is a problem I encountered before, so I assumed it was something general) I guess I was too lazy there. I'll try to reproduce it.

Comment: I get that output with LuaLaTeX, but it's correct with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg Hm, I get an error with XeLaTeX: `! The font "xits" cannot be found.` – must be TeXlive2011.`

Comment: @K.Stm. I always use the "Postscript name", in this case "XITS Math".

Comment: @egreg Well, I get: `! The font "XITS Math" cannot be found.`

Comment: Try xits-math.otf. XeTeX needs the filename

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason loading Asana Math changed the subscript shift drop parameter from 0.5pt to 2.22pt (probably the later value is derived from Asana Math).

You can see reset the value by setting `\luatexUmathsubshiftdrop\textstyle=0.5pt`, but it have to be called inside the formula, so you have to append it to the `\everymath` token:

```
\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath\luatexUmathsubshiftdrop\textstyle=0.5pt}
```

You probably want to the the same for display math:

```
\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\luatexUmathsubshiftdrop\displaystyle=0.5pt}
```

To keep the things compatible with XeTeX, use `\ifluatex`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathbb}]{Asana-Math.otf}

\ifluatex
  \everymath=\expandafter{%
    \the\everymath%
    \luatexUmathsubshiftdrop\textstyle=0.5pt}
  \everydisplay=\expandafter{%
    \the\everydisplay%
    \luatexUmathsubshiftdrop\displaystyle=0.5pt}
\fi

\begin{document}
  $\deg_s \phi_s$
\end{document}
```

Comment: A similar fix seems to be needed with Latin Modern Math.