# How to change default subscript drop value in unicode-math / fontspec?

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, chemmacros, fira-sans

In switching from PDFLaTeX and `typeface` to XeLaTeX and `fontspec` I encountered a difference in which subscripts are placed with respect to the baseline. This seems to be an older issue given the questions asked about that positioning on this forum. See for example  [How to get the numeric subscript and superscript to scale correctly using specific font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457460/how-to-get-the-numeric-subscript-and-superscript-to-scale-correctly-using-specif), [subscript is set too low in math-mode with xits-math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82113/subscript-is-set-too-low-in-math-mode-with-xits-math) or [Placement of subscripts using unicode-math. Is it XeTeX bug?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40349/placement-of-subscripts-using-unicode-math-is-it-xetex-bug).

In my case it's probably related to the different sans serif fonts I use for the compunds created with `chemmacros`. In PDFlaTeX I use(d) `Tex Gyre Heros` and in XeLaTeX I switched to `Fira Sans` (see my previous question / answer as to why: [Non-Latin characters disappear compiling in XeLaTex, but not in PDFLaTeX using Typeface](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671707/non-latin-characters-disappear-compiling-in-xelatex-but-not-in-pdflatex-using-t)).

The outputs below show the difference in the PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX outputs with `TeX Gyre Heros` and `Fira Sans`. For some reason `unicode-math` used in XeLaTeX places the indexes of chemical compounds - the subscripts - slightly lower. It may seem nothing, but it actually affects readability of a text containing several lines containing compounds. So how can I alter the way the subscripts are positioned?

The `unicode-math` package lists a set of features about `\fontdimen` on pages 25-27 of the manual. Can these commands be used to achieve that?

PDFLaTeX / TeX Gyre Heros output: [image]

XeLaTeX / TeX Gyre Heros output: [image]

XeLaTeX / Fira Sans output: [image]

The MWE used in these examples:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

%----- lettertypen -----
\usepackage[charter,cal=cmcal]{mathdesign}

\usepackage[sans-style=upright]{unicode-math} % automatically loads fontspec package
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{GFS Artemisia}[Scale=1.05,]
\setsansfont{FiraSans}[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldFont = *-Medium,
    BoldItalicFont = *-MediumItalic]

%----- chemie -----
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{greek=mathdesign,formula=chemformula}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{format=\sffamily}

%----- layout pakketten -----
\usepackage[body={17.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.0cm]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%===== =====

\begin{document}
    
    Default \verb*|\sffamily| font is \textsf{Fira Sans Regular}: \ch{C2H3ClIOH}
    
\end{document}
```

To obtain the output of the TeX Gyre Heros font the following changes were made in the MWE:

```
\setsansfont{texgyreheros}[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-regular,
    ItalicFont = *-italic,
    BoldFont = *-bold,
    BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic]
```

and

```
Default \verb*|\sffamily| font is \textsf{TeX Gyre Heros}: \ch{C2H3ClIOH}
```

Comment: why do you switch to xelatex instead of lualatex?

Comment: No particular reason. Just compiled a few documents I was working using Lualatex. So far I couldn't see a difference except one, which is more related missing characters / glyphs to the fonts I am using: XeLaTeX then shows an empty box, whereas LuaLaTeX just leaves an empty space.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have learned to look behind the comments you post, but I fail to see your point this time. Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: lualatex offers more options to adapt fonts on the fly.